# Get all Collections that are declared on document Swift Firestore Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document (lets call it d1) that has multiple collections.

```
d1(FirestoreDocument) -> Collection1, Collection2, Collection3
```

These collections each have a unique name (in my case a date string with the format dd.MM.yy).
I need to retrieve all the documents that are that one collection. The problem is that I don't know how I can access a collection that I don't know the exact name of. Is there a function for firebase Firestore where you can for example call `document.getAllCollections(completion...)` and then get the documents for each collection individually?

Comment: Im sorry, the title should be "Get all Subcollections that are declared on document Swift Firestore Firebase "

Comment: Why do you not know the name of the collection you are trying to get? e.g. if it was yesterdays collection, it would be named according to yesterdays date, right?

Comment: I do have a lot of dates (for example every weekday of the last year) so that makes it really difficult to loop through all of these. But I have found another solution by adjusting my data structure.

Comment: The question is still unclear; what's the need to loop over collections? Again, since you know the date, then no looping is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for listing all collections called [`.listCollections()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document) however it is a *server-side function*.
[Meaning it's not available for client/mobile libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document:%7E:text=Retrieving%20a%20list%20of%20collections%20is%20not%20possible%20with%20the%20mobile/web%20client%20libraries.)

Since Swift is a mobile language it is not available there to my knowledge.

However, since you're formatting the subcollections as `dd.MM.yy` that means the subcollections are predictable (to a degree), so you could store a list of  the subcollections a document has within it and then iterate over that list as a workaround, or iterate over a breadth of dates.
Another workaround would be to call `listCollections` server-side (assuming you have a server for your application written in Java, Python, Node.js, Go, PHP, C# or Ruby), and send that list of collections as a JSON array back to your client so it can iterate over it.